# How to use fine-grained methods in a struct?

Tags: scope, rust

I have created a small program where I add users to a register. When I take an object oriented approach in Java, it is quite common to decompose functionality into smaller methods, so I have created `addUser` and `findUser` methods for `Register`. When I compile this program I get the following compilation errors. I have read about borrowing, but could not find a way to fix this.

```
struct User {
    userId: u8,
    age: u8,
}
struct Register {
    users: Vec<User>,
}

impl Register {
    // Initialize
    fn init() -> Register {
        Register {
            users: Vec::new()
        }
    }

    // Add user to register, if user does not exist in register
    fn addUser(&mut self, user: User) {
        match self.findUser(user.userId) {
            Some(u) => println!("User exists!"),
            None => self.users.push(user),
        };
    }

    // If user exists, return user, else return None
    fn findUser(&self, userId: u8) -> Option<&User> {
        for user in &self.users {
            if user.userId == userId {
                return Some(&user);
            }
        }
        None
    }
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e82fc16c96e5d1c44584d39c2f8b6dbe&version=stable&backtrace=0))

Compilation error message:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `self.users` as mutable because `*self` is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:18:21
   |
16 |         match self.findUser(user.userId) {
   |               ---- immutable borrow occurs here
17 |             Some(u) => println!("User exists!"),
18 |             None => self.users.push(user),
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
19 |         };
   |         - immutable borrow ends here
```

Comment: Related / possible duplicate: [Rust borrow mutable self inside match expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908383/rust-borrow-mutable-self-inside-match-expression). You can work around this with `if let`, like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=45e1cf8d65c9c25b9a0630de91f6f2bb&version=stable&backtrace=0).

Comment: Note that by the [Rust naming conventions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/style/style/naming/README.html) the method should be called `find_user`.

Comment: Another possible duplicate: [Cannot borrow variable as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable while refactoring a parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667241/cannot-borrow-variable-as-mutable-because-it-is-also-borrowed-as-immutable-while).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why the `rustc` complains

The first thing to do in this case is of course understand why `rustc` thinks what you're doing is not allowed. So let's look at what you're trying to do:

A `Register` contains a vector of `User`s. `findUser` returns a reference into that vector. `addUser` pushes a new `User` into that vector. So far so good. `addUser` uses `findUser` to find an `Option<&User>`. That (optional) reference to a `User` refers to a `User` inside the `users` vector. If a matching `User` is found, the reference in `u` points to a valid `User`, but you ignore it. If no matching `User` is found, no reference exists, but you mutate the vector. Pushing onto the vector, of course, potentially requires a reallocation, which would invalidate references into the vector. However, this is not a problem, as no reference into the vector exists at that point.

But this is where `rustc` (or more concretely: the borrowchecker) falls short: when the borrowchecker sees

```
    match self.findUser(user.userId){
        // ...
    };
```

it concludes that the `Option<&User>` must be live for the entire `match` body, and concludes from that that the `&User` must be live for the entire `match` body. Hence, when you try to push onto `self.users` inside the `match` body, it complains.

## Solutions

One solution is to wait for the borrowchecker to become smarter and figure out that matching an `Option<T>` can ignore `T`'s lifetime in the `None` branch.

A better short-term solution is to painstakingly explain to the borrowchecker that it's fine, by splitting up the checking and the pushing, e.g. as follows:

```
    let is_found = match self.findUser(user.userId){
        Some(u) => { println!("User exists!"); true},
        None => false
    };
    if !is_found {
        self.users.push(user)
    }
```

Another solution uses the fact that you really don't use the `&User` at all here, so that you can just write the following:

```
    if self.findUser(user.userId) // At this point there is still a `&User`
           .is_some() { // Here, it's lifetime is over and there's a `bool` instead
        println!("User exists!")
    } else {
        // No live references into `self.user` exist, mutation is trivially allowed
        self.users.push(user)
    }
```

Yet another solution would be to change the API of `Register` to reflect that you don't want to do anything with that matching user: just make a `fn contains_user(&self, userId: u8) -> bool`.

#### Footnote

By the way, as @starblue already mentioned in comments, the [Rust naming convention](https://doc.rust-lang.org/style/style/naming/README.html) is to use `snake_case` for method names. Also, `init` should probably just be called `new`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old problem, which is someday solved by *non-lexical lifetimes*. Your program is safe, the compiler just is not able to see that (yet!).

There are many ways to work around this problem; here is one possibility ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5aa721bc88dee7bfb45f53ee25d6d8b6&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
fn add_user(&mut self, user: User) {
    let user_pos = self.users.iter().position(|u| u.user_id == user.user_id);
    match user_pos {
        Some(pos) => {
            let u = &self.users[pos];  // get the user like that
            println!("User exists!");
        }
        None => self.users.push(user),
    }
}
```

**The key insight**: we find the *position* in the vector first and use that position *later* to index the vector. This *delays* referencing something inside the vector.

---

A few additional notes:

- I got rid of the `findUser` method: it's a super common algorithm, so there are shortcuts already. I recommend you getting familiar with the [`Iterator` API](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) to write very brief and easy to read algorithms.
- I changed the names to match the idiomatic naming in Rust: `snake_case`.
- Searching through the vector every time is in O(n); it takes linear time. Inserting n users into your register has a time complexity of O(n²). This is probably not what you want. Why not use a set data structure, like [`HashSet`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html) or [`BTreeSet`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeSet.html)?

Comment: Non-lexical lifetimes solve only the problem that crops up when you inline the `findUser` method or otherwise replace it with code that doesn't call a method on `self` to find the user. Which is still nice but not the only aspect of the question.